# How to target this i tag

Tags: javascript, css, sass, frontend

I am trying to move two `<i>` tags inside of an input tag as a part of a success and error message, but I can't figure out how to target the `<i>` tag inside of my div elements. I am using bootstrap classes :

```css
.fa-check-circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="mb-3 input-control">
  <label for="full-name">Full name\User name</label><br>
  <p>*You can only have on user name per e-mail account</p>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="full-name" name="full-name" placeholder="Full name">
  <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
  <small class="error-name">error</small>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant information for how/when you're trying to target those elements? What are you trying to *do* to them? Presumably you've got some validation checks happening, and in those checks is when you wish to target/select the `<i>` elements? Can you share that code? In this case context is important, because with CSS (and therefore the `querySelector()`/`querySelectorAll()` methods) they can be targeted using `i`, `.fas`, `input ~ i`...but it depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: it depends on the specificity criteria you need to adopt. In such scenario it could be more than enough to use: `div.input-control>i` saying you want the elements of type <i> as direct children of divs having the class input-control

Comment: Input elements are empty (hence no closing tag), so *i* elements (or any other type of element) can't be "inside" one. They can be selected with `document.querySelectorAll('div.mb-3 > i')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector you need is

```
.input-control>input[type=text]~i.fas
```

```css
.input-control>input[type=text]~i.fas {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-1.5em, .2em);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div class="mb-3 input-control">
  <label for="full-name">Full name\User name</label><br>
  <p>*You can only have on user name per e-mail account</p>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="full-name" name="full-name" placeholder="Full name">
  <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
</div>
<div class="mb-3 input-control">
  <label for="full-name2">Full name\User name</label><br>
  <p>*You can only have on user name per e-mail account</p>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="full-name2" name="full-name" placeholder="Full name">
  <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
  <small class="error-name">error</small>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to achieve something like this?

```css
.inputDiv {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50%;
}

#full-name {
    width: 80%;
    border: none;
}

#full-name:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="mb-3 input-control">
  <label for="full-name">Full name\User name</label><br>
  <p>*You can only have on user name per e-mail account</p>
  <div class='inputDiv'>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="full-name" name="full-name" placeholder="Full name">
    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
    <small class="error-name">error</small>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: yes that is basically what I want but with the tag <i>

Comment: It does not matter i or another tag, you can put any element you want inside @JanoszКрајишник